# What would the negation of these two statements be?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I need to negate these two statements and I believe that I have the quantifiers correct, but I'm not completely sure how to negate the math statements. I think I would keep the equations before the equal signs the same but I'm still unsure how to negate the last parts.

Here are the statements I want to negate:

Statement 1: $$\exists x,y\in\mathbb{R}_{\geq0}, \sqrt{9x^2+y^2}\neq 3x+y.$$

Statement 2: $$\forall x\in\mathbb{R}_{\geq0},\sqrt{25x^2+9}=5x+3.$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To negate this, just negate each part of it. Universal quantifiers become existential quantifiers, existential become universal, equality becomes non-equality. So applied to your statements you have that the negation of statement 1 is

$$\forall x,y\in\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0} : \sqrt{9x^2+y^2}=3x+y.$$

Notice what this actually says. Your original statement says that $\sqrt{9x^2+y^2}$ and $3x+y$ are not always equal, as there are some $x,y\in\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ for which it does not hold. Therefore the negation is naturally that they are equal for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$. In much the same way the negation of the second statement is

$$\exists x\in\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0} : \sqrt{25x^2+9}\neq 5x+3.$$

Comment: Ok so I never needed to change the actual math equations themselves, mainly just the equal signs and the quantifiers, this is a huge help. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The negation of "There are $x$ such that blah happens" is "There aren't any $x$ such that blah happens" or in other words "For all $x$ blah *doesn't* happen".  SO the negation of $\exists k, P(k)$ would be $\forall k, \lnot P(k)$.

So the negation of "There exists some $x,y \in \mathbb R_{\ge 0}$ so that $\sqrt{9x^2 + y^2} \ne 3x+y$" would be "For every $x,y\in \mathbb R_{\ge 0}$ it will not be true that $\sqrt{9x^2+y^2}\ne 3x+y$".   Now the negation of $M \ne N$ is, of course, $M=  N$.  So the negation of $\exists x,y \in \mathbb R_{\ge 0},\sqrt{9x^2 + y^2} \ne 3x+y$ would be $\forall x,y \in \mathbb R_{\ge 0}\sqrt{9x^2 + y^2} = 3x+y$ (Obviously not true by the way).

Negating "For all $x$, blah happens" is similar.  The negation is "It is not always the case that for $x$, blah happens" or in other words, "there is some $x$ where blah *doesn't* happen".  So the negation of $\forall k, P(k)$ wolud be $\exists k, \lnot P(k)$.

Which means the negation of $\forall x\in \mathbb R_{\ge 0}, \sqrt{25x^2 +9}=5x+3$ is $\exists x\in \mathbb R_{\ge 0}, \sqrt{25x^2 + 9} \ne 5x+3$.  (Obviously true by the way).

....

You should have $\lnot(\exists k, P(x)) \iff \forall k, \lnot P(k)$ and $\lnot(\forall k, P(k)) \iff \exists k, \lnot P(k)$ tatooed on your forehead. I did. (Which in hindsight was a bad idea as I can't actually see it....)